# algorithms for modular inverses

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers

i have read  section about The Extended Euclidean Algorithm & Modular Inverses,which states that it not only computes `GCD(n,m)` but also  a and b such that `a*n+b*b=1;` 
algorithm is described by by this way:

> 1. Write down n, m, and the two-vectors (1,0) and (0,1)
> 2. Divide the larger of the two numbers by the smaller - call this
>      quotient q
> 3. Subtract q times the smaller from the larger (ie reduce the larger
>      modulo the smaller)

(i have question here   if we  denote  by q   n/m,then `n-q*m is` not equal to 0?because  q=n/m;(assume that n>m),so why it is  necessary  such kind of  operation?
then  4  step

> 4.Subtract q times the vector corresponding to the smaller from the
>   vector corresponding to the larger
>   5.Repeat steps 2 through 4 until the result is zero
>   6.Publish the preceding result as gcd(n,m)

so my question   for this problem also is how can i implement this  steps in code?please help me,i dont know  how start  and from which   point could i start to  solve such problem,for clarify  result  ,it should  look like this
An example of this algorithm is the following computation of 30^(-1)(mod 53);

```
53           30           (1,0)                        (0,1)
53-1*30=23   30           (1,0)-1*(0,1)=(1,-1)         (0,1)
23           30-1*23=7    (1,-1)                       (0,1)-1*(1,-1)=(-1,2)
23-3*7=2      7           (1,-1)-3*(-1,2)=(4,-7)       (-1,2)
2             7-3*2=1     (4,-7)                      (-1,2)-3*(4,7)=(-13,23)
2-2*1=0       1           (4,-7)-2*(-13,23)=(30,-53)   (-13,23)
```

From this we see that gcd(30,53)=1 and, rearranging terms, we see that 1=-13*53+23*30,
so we conclude that 30^(-1)=23(mod 53).

Comment: for more information please see this site http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rcampbel/NumbThy/Class/BasicNumbThy.html and see this section  The Extended Euclidean Algorithm & Modular Inverses

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.  Regarding step 3: q is the integer part of n/m, so the remainder n-q*m can be nonzero.

Comment: i am also confused  @Grammin  i dont know where  store  result when for instance  make  vectors operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The division is supposed to be integer division with truncation. The standard EA for `gcd(a, b)` with `a <= b` goes like this:

```
 b =  a * q0 + r0
 a = r0 * q1 + r1
r0 = r1 * q2 + r2
  ...
r[N+1] = 0
```

Now `rN` is the desired GCD. Then you back-substitute:

```
r[N-1] = r[N] * q[N+1]

r[N-2] = r[N-1] * q[N] + r[N]
       = (r[N] * q[N+1]) * q[N] + r[N]
       = r[N] * (q[N+1] * q[N] + 1)

r[N-3] = r[N-2] * q[N-1] + r[N-1]
       = ... <substitute> ...
```

Until you finally reach `rN = m * a + n * b`. The algorithm you describe keeps track of the backtracking data right away, so it's a bit more efficient.

If `rN == gcd(a, b) == 1`, then you have indeed found the multiplicative inverse of `a` modulo `b`, namely `m`: `(a * m) % b == 1`.